# Error in string.gsub with backslash

Tags: lua, gsub

```
local a = "te\st"
local b = string.gsub(a,'\','\\\\')
assert(false,b)
```

What am I doing wrong?

When I do `assert`, I want that to the screen the string `te\st` will be printed... but it's not working

I have a JSON file, that I want to decode it into Lua table. I don't need to print out nothing, I did the `assert` just to test a local problem.

So what I need is to keep all data in the JSON file that has `'\'`.

Comment: I assume that if i solve that small example, i will be able to use the same solution for the JSON part

Comment: Please specify what is in `b` and what do you expect/want the result to be to get better answers

Comment: Mind explaining your problem a little better / with more code inlcuding the json part?

Answer (score 3):

Use `[[]]` instead of `""` or `''` if you don't want backslash to have special meaning.

Read about literal strings [in the manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.1).

Comment: hi, this might be the solution. i get the string in JSON format. and i want to keep all data that has '\' as it is. so i rather not add [[]] in the JSON code. i rather take care of it from lua

Comment: In Lua backslashes have special meaning *only* in string literals (i.e. in strings which you typed directly in the code). If your data is in "JSON format", then backslashes in it are likely to be interpreted by JSON rules by whichever Lua library you use to load JSON. It is hard to say, as you do not provide sufficient details.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried escaping it with the `%` character instead of `\`

I don't know if this will help, but I was having a HELL of a time making Lua's `gsub` match my string with special characters in it that I wanted treated literally... it turned out that instead of using `\` as an escape character, or doubling the character, that I needed to prefix the special character with `%` to make it be treated literally.

Comment: Yes, depending on which version of LUA you're using, it will either accept \ and % as escape characters (older versions)  or just % (newer versions)

Answer (score 0):

Your question wasn't too clear so I'm not 100% sure what you mean. Do you mean that you want the assert to fire when b is equal to the string "te\st"? If so you can do a simple:

```
assert(b ~= "te\st")
```

Or I suppse...

```
assert(b ~= a)
```

Comment: Hi, i will clarify my question. i have a JSON file, that i want to decode it into lua table.  i don't need to print out nothing, i did the assert just to test a local problem. So what i need is to keep all data in the JSON file that has '\'

Comment: Please update your question with this information (and provide a working minimal example)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the gsub. But here it is anyways.

```
local a = "te\\st"
local b = string.gsub(a,'\\','\\')
assert(false,b)
```

Comment: hi, this solution doesn't work. what other method i can use instead of the gsub ?